# Toggle option in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to show in Tableau a line plot having option to toggle between month on month and week on week changes in same view?

Currently the view is at monthly level as shown below and I want to switch to weekly option in same view.

[image]

Here is the snapshot of my data.

[image]

Comment: See the answer below! Do tell if it worked or if you require some modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm replicating a solution/answer (workaround) on sample superstore data

- Let's assume your view is something like this GIF

[image]

- Add a parameter say `toggle parameter` with values 1 and 2 only display these as monthly view and weekly view respectively.
- Add a calculated field say `new order date` with the following calculation

```
CASE [Toggle parameter]
WHEN 1 THEN DATETRUNC('month', [Order Date])
WHEN 2 THEN DATETRUNC('week', [Order Date])
END
```

- Add this field on view instead of `[order date]` and see you can get a viz like this

[image]

- Finally you can edit the display values/axis as per taste